# Jaynes' Derivation of Herschel-Maxwell for Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I am reading the following paper:

http://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/cc07s.pdf

and cannot seem to figure out how Jaynes is deriving (P2) and below (specifically the log arithmetic log[f(x)/f(0)]....)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you put some details in your question please, firstly so readers of your question are not required to go read a paper to understand the question, and secondly, to protect your question from the possibility that the link will disappear (at which point it becomes not so much a useful resource for others as junk cluttering up the site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation 
$$
  f(x)f(y)=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \qquad (*)
$$ 
holds for every $x,y$. If $y=0$, then $(*)$ gives $g(|x|)=f(x)f(0)$ for every $x$. Using this in $(*)$ to "eliminate" $g$, we have $f(x)f(y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})f(0)$. Dividing by $(f(0))^2$ and taking the log on both sides we find
$$
  \frac{f(x)f(y)}{f(0)f(0)}=\frac{f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{f(0)} \, ,
$$
$$
  \log\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(0)}\right)+\log\left(\frac{f(y)}{f(0)}\right)= \log\left( \frac{f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{f(0)}\right) \, .
$$

Comment: In this video, it's explained step-by-step in a very detalied manner:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTyPuZ9-JZ0